# ClearCase view visible with lsview, nonexistent for catcs

Tags: clearcase

**On a machine I'm working on, there's this view we shall call `magic_view`  - which exhibits the following strange behavior:

```
$ ct lsview magic_view
  magic_view /view_store/our_team_vws/magic_view.vws
$ ct catcs -tag magic_view
ct: Error: View tag "magic_view": ClearCase object not found
```

Now, `magic_view` was not created by me, so I'm guessing something strange happened to it. But - what? What could cause a view to be visible for `lsview` but unknown for `catcs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the view has been registered ([`cleartool register -view`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ca/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_register.htm))

But its tag has not been declared ([`cleartool mktag -view`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ca/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktag.htm))

```
cleartool register -view -replace -host newhost -hpath hpath/xxx.vws /hpath/xxx.vws
ct mktag -view -replace -tag tag -host newhost -gpath gpath gpath
```

The tag part of this picture is missing in your case:

[image: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/images/rgy_1_region.gif]

You can see more [`cleartool mktag -view` examples here](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/mktag/mktag.htm).

Its tag might be missing from the [client **region**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/c_rgy_data_regions.htm):

Example: to create a windows tag from a UNIX server, for a ClearCase View with its view storage on a NAS device:

```
cleartool mktag -view -tag samecs_view -region samecs_win -host view_server_host.samecs.com \
-gpath "\\\\samecs\\ccviewstore \\gbush_view.vws" \
-hpath "\\\\samecs\\ccviewstore \\gbush_view.vws" \
/net/samecs/ccviewstore/gbush_view.vws
```

As [Brian Cowan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4223401/brian-cowan) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575189/clearcase-view-visible-with-lsview-nonexistent-for-catcs#comment110670590_62577245), using the [`rgy_check`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rgy_check.htm) command can help.

> That will tell you about cc registry issues.
> At one time, there were issues getting the configspec of snapshot views if you weren't actually IN the view, but that currently works.

Comment: I've only ever created views with `mkview`. I suppose `mkview` performs these two actions, one after another?

Comment: @einpoklum Sure, but once created (meaning registered + tagged), one perfectly can `rmtag -view` it. The view is still there, its name is just missing. Here, you don't have to re-create the view (no more "`mkview`"). You only have to tag it.

Comment: You may want to run rgy_check -views. The executable is either in {cc install}/etc or {cc install}\bin depending on the OS. That will tell you about cc registry issues. At one time, there were issues getting the configspec of snapshot views if you weren't actually IN the view, but that currently works.